# Can a Web User Control (.ascx) use a CSS file for styling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-2, ascx

Here's the source of a blank .acsx file I created called LogOnBox.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LogOnBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="ECommerce.Views.Shared.LogOnBox" %>
```

I want to drag some labels, and textboxes etc and give them style using a CSS file. How can I associate a CSS to an acsx file?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?  The solution is different for each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS is associated to the page, and not the control specifically. But you can use the CSS in the control when the page has referenced it.

Comment: So how do you suggest I apply an html id to a part of my webcontrol?

Answer (score 1):

Just reference the css file in the header of the page containing the user control.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. This is true no matter how you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

In my cases i would like to embed css and js file into dll
for do that i do bellow steps and it work 
**step 1**
Put bellow code on top of your page behind

```
   [assembly:WebResource("YourProjectName.Assets.Plugins.Dropzone.dist.dropzone.js",    "application/x-javascript")]
[assembly:WebResource("YourProjectName.Assets.Plugins.Dropzone.dist.dropzone.css","text/css")]
namespace Sanay.Suip.UserControls
{
    public partial class FileUpload : UserControlBase
    {
```

**step 2**
And in inInitial event by bellow codes

```
`protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

base.OnInit(e);
string css = "<link href=\"" + Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(),
"YourProjectName.Assets.Plugins.Dropzone.dist.dropzone.css") + "\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "cssFile", css, false);
ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
csm.RegisterClientScriptResource(GetType(), "YourProjectName.Assets.Plugins.Dropzone.dist.dropzone.js");
}
```

`