# Including js/css file in control or extension method to html helper class in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a grid control, in which i want use some javascipt. I added a js file into the class library project and set its Buid Action to "Embded Resource". 
But the js/jquery functions (Implemented in js file) are not accessing, also i am not able to view the included js file in other project where i am using that dll, everything is working fine expect this one.

Please provide some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have an Action method in your `Controller`. Using reflection you can read the resourceName and return it as `FileStreamResult`. In the view add script path as `/Controller/Action/actualjsfile.js`

[Refer to this Blog Post as well](http://toreaurstad.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/simple-access-of-embedded-resources-in.html)

**Steps on tested sample as follows**

Create class library project (JSDLL)

add `TestJS.js` as embedded resource (file contents as shown below)

```
function MyAlert() {
    alert("Hello! this is from the dll");
}
```

In AssemblyInfo.cs add the following (need to add reference to System.Web.dll)

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("JSDLL.TestJS.js", "application/x-javascript")]
```

Compile class library project and add as reference to your MVC project

In your controller add the following action (same as the blog post; but with minor modifications)

```
    public FileStreamResult ContentFile(string id)
    {
        string resourceName = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(JSDLL.Class1)).GetManifestResourceNames().ToList().FirstOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith(id));
        return new FileStreamResult(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(JSDLL.Class1)).GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName), "text/javascript");
    }
```

Simple View to test (have a look at how the `.js` file is referenced. `onClick` I am calling the function from the `.js` file)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
     Put content here.     
     <button type="button" onclick="MyAlert()">Text</button>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Home/ContentFile/TestJS.js"/>
```

output

[image]

**EDITED (for Matthew's comment)**

here are few screen shots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with subfolders? I'm trying to have themes embedded in my dll.

Comment: @MatthewGrima I guess you want your js file to be under a folder in the  class library project (dll). Nothing needs to be changed; it should work with the same implementation as in the answer I've provided. Did you try it? it should work (I've tried this & it works fine)

Comment: I wouldn't be able to resolve /Home/ContentFile/js/test.js

I'm trying to achieve that but I think I need to hack around MapRoutes to get there(if possible)

Comment: @MatthewGrima I've edited my answer with few screen shots. Hope this is what you are after.

Comment: +1 for your help, although that isn't what I'm asking (probably because I'm being a bit vague).


You you are requesting the js file like so: <script type="text/javascript" src="/Home/ContentFile/TestJS.js"/>. Even though it's inside /js/TestJS.js. I'm trying to find a way to request it like this <script type="text/javascript" src="/Home/ContentFile/js/TestJS.js"/>

As I said, I do not think it's possible, but one can hope :)

Comment: @MatthewGrima I am not sure why you need this. With the default route map in MVC it takes the format Controller/Action/id. You can define your own custom route map and achieve what you want. There are plenty of articles on this. Google for the help. here is one http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"Embded Resource" makes your `js` file part of the dll therefore you can not view it in other projects.

`js` file is suppose to be access from your javascript code and you don't need to embed it in a dll.

Comment: Thanks, i will do the same (take a look of this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930.aspx) but what next ?

Comment: Change the property from "Embeded resource" to "none" and carry the file along with your dll.

Comment: You mean, will manually add that js file in each view where ever anyone use that extension method ? if Yes then i would like to mention i want to add it dynamically at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed CSS/JS in the DLL, you'll need to reference them differently than just using the file name. Check out http://www.karpach.com/Custom-ASP-NET-server-control-with-embedded-resources.htm for information about it (it's for ASP.NET 2.0, but it should give you some idea to start with).

Also, check out this [stackoverflow question] on whether or not you should embed those resources.

[1] [Should I embed CSS/JavaScript files in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190358/should-i-embed-css-javascript-files-in-a-web-application)